# WordPress admin: How do I move a submenu from one parent to another?

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

Is there a way to move a sub-menu item from one parent to another? I need to do it without any plugin.

I have following menu hierarchy in admin at the moment

> Weather Alerts
>    - Weather Alerts
>    - Add New
>
> Weather Settings
>    - Weather Settings
>    - Global Weather Settings

I have a user role named 'Weather Info Editor'. For users with this role I like the menu to come up like

> Weather Alerts
>    - Global Weather Settings
>    - Weather Alerts
>    - Add New

and parent menu **Weather Settings** to disappear.

To get this done I tried the following but it does not work:

```
function remove_menu_pages_for_weather_info_editor() {
    if(current_user_can('weather-info-editor')) {
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=seminar');
        remove_menu_page('jetpack');
        remove_menu_page( 'weather-settings');
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_pages_for_weather_info_editor', 999);

function move_global_settings_under_weather_alert() {
    if(current_user_can('weather_info_editor')) {
        add_submenu_page(
            'edit.php?post_type=weather_alert',
            'Global Weather Settings',
            'Global Weather Settings',
            'manage_options',
            'global_weather_settings'
        );
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'move_global_settings_under_weather_alert', 9);
```

I also tried `'weather_alert'` in place of `'edit.php?post_type=weather_alert',` in function `move_global_settings_under_weather_alert` but that did not work either.

I am using [this](https://markwilkinson.me/2014/11/altering-wordpress-admin-menus/) as reference.

Please suggest a way to accomplish the way.